# PHP value is a string and boolean need the value as a number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to improve a woocommerce plugin to add an additional field in a report.

A value of $25.80 is displayed via the variable $item['order_price']

What I am trying to do is convert the value to a number of 25.80 so that I can run a calculation with it. I have tried numerous methods all of which have been unsuccessful (see below).
When I run the following code var_dump($item['order_price'])
it returns the following string(128) "$25.80"

Any ideas how I can convert this to a number for calculating?

Thanks in advance

```
# Returns 0 
<?php echo intval($item['order_price']); ?>

# Returns 0 
<?php echo (int)$item['order_price']; ?>

# Returns 0 
<?php echo( intval($item['order_price'])); ?>

# Returns 0 
<?php  $item_price = ( Number($item['order_price'])); ?>

# Return 200 OK
<?php   $unit_price = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $item['order_price']);  ?>

# Returns $25.80
strval($item['order_price']);

# Retuns 0
<?php echo floatval($item['order_price']); ?>

# Retuns 1
<?php echo settype($item['order_price'], integer); ?>

# Retuns True 
<?php echo (boolval($item['order_price']) ? 'true' : 'false')."\n"; ?>

# Returns String 
<?php echo "order price -".gettype($item['order_price']); ?>

# Retuns False
<?php var_dump(is_float($item['order_price'])); ?>

# Retuns $25.801
<?php echo print_r($item['order_price']); ?>

# Retuns 128
<?php echo strlen($item['order_price']); ?>

# Reurns Null
<?php echo substr($item, 0, 5); ?>

# Reurns Null
<?php echo mb_substr($item, 0, 5); ?>
```

Comment: I answered below, but your `print_r` case is interesting in its own right. `print_r` causes the value to be written to output (in this case "$25.80"). No need to echo that. However, `print_r` also returns a value of true (1) when it is successful. So `print_r` wrote "$25.80" and then returned 1, which was then written by the `echo` command. `print_r` has a second parameter you can use to say "don't actually print this, just give me the result." `echo print_r($item['order_price'], true)` would return the expected "$25.80".

Comment: <?php print_r($item['order_price']); ?> I just checked again came back with a value of $25.80

Comment: Yes, it was `echo print_r(...)` that created the interesting result. But that is not directly related to your question, just an observation about that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `$` that's messing you up. Try `trim($item['order_price'], '$')` and turn that into a float.

Edit to add: you could also use `substr` or a few other methods to remove the `$`, but the above states very nicely your intent, which means the next person will understand instantly what that line of code is there to to.

Edit again to add: The `trim` function does not alter the provided string, it returns a new, trimmed string.

```
$price = floatval(trim($item['order_price'], '$'));
```

please see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: I tried trim($item['order_price'], '$') and the result was returned as $25.80. I am wondering if the string length is possibly the problem

Comment: `echo trim('$25.80', '$')` prints `25.80` - I think you are dropping the result of that operation elsewhere in your logic.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your help. I used the below and each row came back with the value of null <? $price = floatval(trim($item['order_price'], '$')); ?>
    <td class="price"><?php var_dump($price); ?></td>

Comment: Just start with `print 'order price = ' . $item['order_price'] . '      trimmed = ' . trim($item['order_price'], '$');` Look at the before and after with the trimmed value, get it like you want it, then add `floatval` and all the formatting.

Comment: Due to the unknown extra characters resulting in `string(128) "$25.80"` Suggest using `trim(..., " \n\r\t\v\x00\$")` to include the default characters and dollar sign or `trim(trim(...), '$')` but may run into an issue with the thousands separator if it is included.

Answer (score 0):

After some work I finally managed to resolve this issue with Jerry pointing me in the right direction.

The string containing the value had multiple characters to deal with and when left with only numbers I notice extra numbers that should not have been there that had been added by the developer to prevent editing the string easily.

Final result looks like this

```
<td class="quantity"><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
<?php
        $unit_price = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $item['order_price']);
        $unit_price = substr($unit_price, 2);
        $clean_price = (floatval($unit_price) / floatval($item['quantity']));
        $clean_price = number_format($clean_price, 2, '.', ',');
?>
<td class="price"><?php echo '$'. $clean_price; ?></td>
```

Comment: With the character set matching group `[]`, you do not need the `+` which means 1 or more in a row. Just `'/[^0-9.]/'` is sufficient to remove all characters except numbers and periods.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, please consider using [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) to both parse the currency to a float value and output the float value in the desired currency.

Example: https://3v4l.org/XmE3h

```
$item['order_price'] = '$25.80';

$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

$decimal = $fmt->parseCurrency($item['order_price'], $cur);
var_dump($decimal, $cur);

$currency = $fmt->formatCurrency($decimal, $cur);
var_dump($currency);
```

**Result**

```
float(25.8)
string(3) "USD"

string(6) "$25.80"
```

---

Although `string(128) "$25.80"` does not make sense, perhaps there is additional hidden characters in the variable? If it is just white-space, use `trim($item['order_price'])`